# Search data gridview using textbox and checkboxlist asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to use textbox and checkboxlist to search data in gridview using asp.net c#. Using textbox can search the data. But for checkboxlist only can search the data when check only one checkbox. If check more than one checkbox, can't search the data. thanks a lot for helping.

the code:

c# code

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (cblDay.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        foreach (ListItem val in cblDay.Items)
        {
            if (val.Selected == true)
            {

                RptRateData.Day += val.Value + "";
            }

        }
    }


    RptRateData.RateAmount = txtRate.Text.Trim();

    BindGrid();
}
```

code for class:

```
public string RateAmount { get; set; }
public string Day { get; set; }

internal DataSet GetRptRateSet()
        {

            DataSet tmpDS = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                string strSQL = @"SELECT  ComplexRateInfo.ComplexRateId, 
                                ComplexRateDetailInfo.Day,  
                                ComplexRateInfo.RateAmount 
                                FROM ComplexRateInfo  
                                LEFT JOIN ComplexRateDetailInfo ON ComplexRateInfo.ComplexRateId = ComplexRateDetailInfo.ComplexRateId ";
                string whereSQL = " WHERE";
                string orderBySQL = " order by  Day ;";
                int filterCount = 0; //to keep track of needed filter that are going to be used by the sql string
                string[] sIndex = new string[2]; //to keep track of scalar variable needed by the sql, four string of sIndex because maximum filter available is 4
                int indexCount = 0; //count to access sIndex members


                //filter with or without day
                if (_ds.Day != null && _ds.Day != "")
                {
                    if (filterCount > 0) //query need additional filter
                        whereSQL = whereSQL + " AND ComplexRateDetailInfo.Day LIKE '{" + filterCount + "}'";
                    else //if this is the first filter
                        whereSQL = whereSQL + " ComplexRateDetailInfo.Day LIKE '{" + filterCount + "}'";

                    filterCount++;
                    sIndex[indexCount] = _ds.Day;
                    indexCount++;

                }


                //filter with or without rate amount
                if (_ds.RateAmount != null && _ds.RateAmount != "")
                {
                    if (filterCount > 0) //query need additional filter
                        whereSQL = whereSQL + " AND ComplexRateInfo.RateAmount LIKE '{" + filterCount + "}'";
                    else //if this is the first filter
                        whereSQL = whereSQL + " ComplexRateInfo.RateAmount LIKE '{" + filterCount + "}'";

                    filterCount++;
                    sIndex[indexCount] = _ds.RateAmount;
                    indexCount++;

                }

                //build complete query with no filter at all
                if (filterCount == 0)
                {
                    strSQL = strSQL + orderBySQL;
                    tmpDS = Db.GetDataSet(string.Format(strSQL));
                }

                //build complete query with 1 or more filter
                else
                {
                    strSQL = strSQL + whereSQL + orderBySQL;
                    tmpDS = Db.GetDataSet(string.Format(strSQL, sIndex));
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return tmpDS;
        }
```

Comment: please show your source code too

Comment: source code? actually i don't know how to call selected value checkboxlist into class

Comment: gridview code just "protected void gvRptRate_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvRptRate.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindGrid();
    }"

Comment: the gridview just display the data. Cannot Edit or Delete.

Comment: already update at above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. Assigning values to `RptRateData.Day` from CheckBoxList.

**Description:** You assign selected values to object without using any separator. So For example if you have selected 1, 2, 4 days then as per your code, value of `RptRateData.Day` will be 124. Instead of that, it should be separated with comma as shown below:

```
    var selectedDays = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem val in cblDay.Items)
    {
        if (val.Selected == true)
        {

            selectedDays += "'" + val.Value + "',";
        }
    }

RptRateData.Day = selectedDays.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' });
```

2. Now come to the second point which is in your SQL query which you make dynamically.

**Description:** In this query in `WHERE` clause you use `Like` operator for `ComplexRateDetailInfo.Day`. This will not work anymore. Instead of that you should use `IN` operator.

**Note:** Are you sure that your **Like** operator is working with curly braces ('{' and '}') and without '%' symbol ?

Comment: just change LIKE to IN? or need other changes. because when I change to IN, the gridview not filter. thanks

Comment: and first point also. and also change syntax to use `IN` operator http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp Don't forget to Upvote and mark as an answer if it help you. So that other developers can get solution facing same issue.

Comment: sorry, it's look like this " whereSQL = whereSQL + " AND ComplexRateDetailInfo.Day IN ('{" + filterCount + "}')"; "

Comment: what is value of filtercount ?

Comment: the value get from selectedDays

Comment: but when i do like that the sql query become like this "  WHERE ComplexRateDetailInfo.Day IN ('Monday,Tuesday')   " . But the right one like this " WHERE ComplexRateDetailInfo.Day IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday') "

Comment: change selected value as updated answer. `selectedDays += "'" + val.Value + "',"
`